# use variables set in a script file inside another script file

Tags: shell, variables, variable-assignment

I have set some variables in my shell, because I need them all the time. How can I make a script, that I call on the same shell that has variables set access the variables that are defined in the shell, without passing them explicitely as parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply *source* the script with the assignments in your shell script like so:

```
 . /path/to/settings  # Dot, blank, name of file.
```

This will execute the contents of settings in the current shell (as opposed to starting a subshell, where assignments are lost after the subshell ends.)

Comment: You can also use the verbose form of the ".": "source". `source /path/to/settings/` will also work.

Comment: sweet i didn't know it went this way as well